Pycharm crashes logs out of my session
For the past 3 days I have experienced this issue while using Pycharm on Ubuntu 22.04.4 LTS.
At random times, the operative system would crash into a black screen (bright underscore top left corner) and then return to the log in screen.
I have tried to uninstall anaconda, pycharm, delete the caches, update the operative system and programs to the latest versions but I still experience the same error.
The issue occurs even if no script is launching. I tried to the command  journalctl -b -1 -e and I guess the system does not really crush because my entries are like:
abr 09 17:20:18 foreshadow systemd[1]: Deactivated swap /dev/nvme0n1p8.
abr 09 17:20:18 foreshadow systemd[1]: dev-disk-by\x2duuid-cdbec0dd\x2dcb33\x2d450f\x2d9deb\x2d549709f6d13c.swap: Deactivated successfully.
abr 09 17:20:18 foreshadow systemd[1]: Deactivated swap /dev/disk/by-uuid/cdbec0dd-cb33-450f-9deb-549709f6d13c.
abr 09 17:20:18 foreshadow systemd[1]: Reached target Unmount All Filesystems.
abr 09 17:20:18 foreshadow systemd[1]: Reached target Late Shutdown Services.
abr 09 17:20:18 foreshadow systemd[1]: systemd-reboot.service: Deactivated successfully.
abr 09 17:20:18 foreshadow systemd[1]: Finished System Reboot.
abr 09 17:20:18 foreshadow systemd[1]: Reached target System Reboot.
abr 09 17:20:18 foreshadow systemd[1]: Shutting down.
abr 09 17:20:18 foreshadow systemd-shutdown[1]: Syncing filesystems and block devices.
abr 09 17:20:18 foreshadow systemd-shutdown[1]: Sending SIGTERM to remaining processes...
abr 09 17:20:18 foreshadow systemd-journald[422]: Journal stopped

So I guess it is just been forced to logout.
I wonder if anyone has a suggestion to help identify the cause or I will have to reinstall everything...
Thanks a lot.
